# Convert json object into specific format array using angular 5 or javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have a json data that looks like below.

```
  [{
   {name: "box: 122",x=["2018-01-12T00:01:56.480Z", "2018-01-12T00:05:58.116Z", "2018-01-   12T00:10:00.379Z"], y=[0, 3, 5]},
   {name: "box: 125",x=["2018-01-12T00:01:56.480Z", "2018-01-12T00:05:58.116Z", "2018-01-12T00:10:00.379Z"], y=[1,5,2]}
  }]
```

Now I want to format this json to below format.

output :

```
{ 
box: 122,  "2018-01-12T00:01:56.480Z",  0 
box: 122 ,"2018-01-12T00:05:58.116Z" ,  3
box: 122 ,"2018-01-12T00:10:00.379Z",   5
box: 125,  "2018-01-12T00:01:56.480Z",  1
box: 125, "2018-01-12T00:05:58.116Z",   5
box: 125,  "2018-01-12T00:10:00.379Z"   2
}
```

Basically I will have export this data to csv file.I have tried many code snippet but none of them fulfill desired result. 
 Can anyone help me how to do this in javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSON does not support `=`. Your input and expected outputs are invalid.

Comment: what is the format of output?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp refer this

Comment: I added answer to your post . I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: Your input JSON, as well as output JSON, is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Few observations :**

- Your `JSON` is not a valid `JSON`.
- JSON does not support `=`. use `:` instead of `=`.
- valid JSON should be like **`Array of objects`** **:**

  [image]

**Solution as per the requirement :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{
 "name": "box: 122",
 "x": ["2018-01-12T00:01:56.480Z", "2018-01-12T00:05:58.116Z", "2018-01-12T00:10:00.379Z"],
 "y": [0, 3, 5]
}, {
 "name": "box: 125",
 "x": ["2018-01-12T00:01:56.480Z", "2018-01-12T00:05:58.116Z", "2018-01-12T00:10:00.379Z"],
 "y": [1, 5, 2]
}];

var tableString = "<table>",
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    div = document.createElement('div');
    tableString += "<tr><td>name</td><td>x</td><td>y</td><tr>";

    for (var i in jsonObj) {
        tableString += "<tr>";
        tableString += "<td>" + jsonObj[i].name + "</td>";
        tableString += "<td>" + jsonObj[i].x + "</td>";
        tableString += "<td>" + jsonObj[i].y + "</td>";      
        tableString += "</tr>";
    }

tableString += "</table>";
div.innerHTML = tableString;
body.appendChild(div);
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: yes you are right the json format is look like this.By the way I don't need the table instead I want to export the output into csv file format.

Comment: I tried this 
var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
            var str = '';
            //for i=1:1:i_end
            //array(line)=name(n),",",x(n,i),","y(n,i),\n;
            //line++
            //end
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var line = '';
                for (var index in array[i]) {
                    if (line != '') line += ','

                    line += array[i][index];
                }

                str += line + '\r\n';
            }

            return str;

Comment: then it returns like below:

Comment: I answered as per the OP and it is working as per the requirement.